# Counts of certain fields in linq query

Tags: c#, linq

This is my query, it works fine and gives me expected result;

```
var result2 = (from dt in disMudahaleTipiRepo
               join dm in disMudahaleRepo on dt.Kodu equals dm.MudahaleKodu
               join kr in kurumRepo on dm.CreatedKurumKodu equals kr.KurumKodu
               join yu in userRepo on dm.CreatedBy equals yu.ID
               group dt by new {  yu.Ad, yu.Soyad, kr.KurumAdi } into grp
               select new
               {
                   AdSoyAd = grp.Key.Ad + " " + grp.Key.Soyad,
                   KurumAdi = grp.Key.KurumAdi,
                   KoduSayisi1 = grp.Select(s => s.Kodu).Where(w=>w== "401.030").Count(),
                   KoduSayisi2 = grp.Select(s => s.Kodu).Where(w=>w== "402.090").Count(),
                   KoduSayisi3 = grp.Select(s => s.Kodu).Where(w=>w== "406.020").Count(),
                   KoduSayisi4 = grp.Select(s => s.Kodu).Where(w=>w== "402.020").Count(),
                   KoduSayisi5 = grp.Select(s => s.Kodu).Where(w=>w== "406.070").Count()
                   ...
               });
```

only problem is there are 86 fields more(lol), so it will end up like that:

```
               ...
               select new
               {
                   AdSoyAd = grp.Key.Ad + " " + grp.Key.Soyad,
                   KurumAdi = grp.Key.KurumAdi,
                   KoduSayisi1 = grp.Select(s => s.Kodu).Where(w=>w== "401.030").Count(),
                   ...
                   KoduSayisi91 = grp.Select(s => s.Kodu).Where(w=>w== "436.070").Count()

               });
```

Instead of doing this, I tried to create a dictionary and keep as (Code, Number) its good in theory but how can I tell this to linq?

I don't think definition of entities is necessary here but let me share;

```
public class DisMudahaleTipi : Entity
{
    public string Kodu { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class DisMudahale : AuditableEntity
{
    public string MudahaleKodu { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: i think your case is a dynamic pivot query case. You can not use linq. Please see: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/ Hope it helps

Comment: Why can't you just include `.Kodu` also into your grouping like `group dt by new {  yu.Ad, yu.Soyad, kr.KurumAdi, dt.Kodu } into grp`. Seems like it will give you what you want

Comment: I assume this is LinQ2Entities and not Linq2Objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use a subquery, but I don't have a database at hand to test if the following works:

```
var keys = ["401.300", .. ];
var result = (from dt in disMudahaleTipiRepo
 join dm in disMudahaleRepo on dt.Kodu equals dm.MudahaleKodu
 join kr in kurumRepo on dm.CreatedKurumKodu equals kr.KurumKodu
 join yu in userRepo on dm.CreatedBy equals yu.ID
 group dt by new {  yu.Ad, yu.Soyad, kr.KurumAdi } into grp
 select new
 {
    AdSoyAd = grp.Key.Ad + " " + grp.Key.Soyad,
    KurumAdi = grp.Key.KurumAdi,
    Kudos = (from key in keys
             select new 
             {
                Key = key,
                Amount = grp.Count(w => w.Kudo == key)
             }).ToList(),
}).ToList();
```

**Note:** In addition to the subquery I changed `Select(s=>s.Kudo).Where(w=>w=="...").Count()` to reduce Linq complexity and improve performance.

Comment: I understood your logic here well, I will implement this way thanks man

Comment: Glad I could help